# How to delete \n form string scraped from website

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a text scraped from website (itemHtml.text):

```
 dolar amerykański 1 USD 3.8436
 euro 1 EUR 4.2989
 funt szterling 1 GBP 4.8768
```

How to delete \n from this text? I tryed this:

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.nbp.pl/home.aspx?f=/kursy/kursya.html"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
soup.findAll("tr")

for itemHtml in soup.select('.pad5 tr'):
    currency = ['amerykański', 'euro', 'szterling']
    if itemHtml.find('td'):
        if any (cur in itemHtml.text for cur in currency):
            dane_comma = itemHtml.text
            dane_dot = dane_comma.replace(',', '.')
            dane = dane_dot.replace('\n', ' ')
            print(dane)



</i>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Check out dane_comma.strip() https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip

Comment: Something is off. Is that text in a file, because you have not opened, let alone read it, and where did the `</i>` end italics html tag come from? I suspect you will need to edit your answer and show all your code, before anyone can help you.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony here you are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no newlines (\n) in that text.
What you are seeing is 3 print statements, which gives you 3 lines of output.
e.g.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.nbp.pl/home.aspx?f=/kursy/kursya.html"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
soup.findAll("tr")
single_line = ""
cnt = 0

for itemHtml in soup.select('.pad5 tr'):
    currency = ['amerykański', 'euro', 'szterling']
    if itemHtml.find('td'):
        if any (cur in itemHtml.text for cur in currency):
            dane = itemHtml.text
            dane = dane.replace(',', '.')
            single_line += " "+dane
            cnt += 1
            print("Print count",cnt,dane)
print(single_line.strip())
```

Gives:

```
Print count 1  dolar amerykański 1 USD 3.8436 
Print count 2  euro 1 EUR 4.2989 
Print count 3  funt szterling 1 GBP 4.8768 
dolar amerykański 1 USD 3.8436   euro 1 EUR 4.2989   funt szterling 1 GBP 4.8768
```

With no attempt, in the code, to remove new-line characters (single_line.strip() only being used to remove leading and any following spaces)